# Make repeat value to null for a given record

Tags: sql

I have a table yrstphn with record like below:

```
|  yr  | st | phn  |  
| 2012 | NV | 1234 |
| 2012 | NV | 2361 |
| 2012 | MD | 1234 |
| 2012 | MD | 2361 |
| 2012 | MA | 1234 |
| 2012 | MA | 2361 |
```

I would like to get following by using program (sql or cursor):

```
|  yr  | st | phn  |
| 2012 | NV | 1234 |
| null | MD | 2361 |
| null | MA | null |
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: what's the logic behind the wanted output?

Comment: It is oracle. My customer requested this stating that this format is used to upload data file to an application.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to treat each column as a separate list.  This is not really relational, but you can do it in SQL:

```
select max(yr) as yr, max(st) as st, max(phn) as phn
from ((select row_number() over (order by yr) as seqnum, yr, null as st, null as phn
       from t
       group by year
      ) union all
      (select row_number() over (order by yr) as seqnum, NULL, st, NULL
       from t
       group by year
      ) union all
      (select row_number() over (order by yr) as seqnum, NULL, NULL, phn
       from t
       group by year
      )
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

Comment: That is a brilliant idea. It is exactly what I want. Thank you so much, Gordon.